# Object definition in MS SQL 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

I was looking for a way to generate object definition (in my case stored procedure defintion) in SQL 2000 like I can get in SQL 2005 : select definition from sys.all_sql_modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One place the text is available in SQL2000 is `syscomments`.

The text in each row is limited to 4000 characters, so there will be more than one row for larger objects. In this case the `colid` column identifies the order of the rows (1 being the first chunk, 2 the second, and so on). For instance `sp_WhoIsActive` in the `master` database is long enough to have many rows in `syscomments`.